# LCD panel: black/white frames before and after the normal video data

Tags: lcd

Please have a look at the following power on/power off sequence diagram I have taken from a datasheet for a Full HD LCD panel by AU Optronics:

[image: The LCD panel power on/power off sequence.]

The diagram's notes say:

> Note 1: Insert a black pattern.
> Note 2: Insert a white pattern after valid data and last until VDD falls to 10%.

As I understand the notes, the datasheet tells me to insert a bunch of black frames before my video, and another bunch of white frames after the video. Unfortunately, the datasheet does not explain *why* these black and white frames are needed.

Can someone please teach me their purpose? Are they here for a reason or can be omitted without causing harm to the panel's electronics or liquid crystals?

**UPD:**
The panel model is M240HW01 V8 (and [the datasheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tpgp-YEsakO7D6AdvwhVoP8DHr56cu81/view?usp=sharing); it has no “confidential” stamps or anything, so I think I can publish the link).

Comment: Are you sure it's *you* who must send them, or just that *they* have measured the parameters under those conditions? It would help to know which panel this is or have a link to datasheet.

Comment: @Justme: Yes, the panel does not seem to insert these frames by itself, it just leaves pixels in their latest state if I stop sending video. And I added a link to the datasheet to the post.

Comment: "can [they] be omitted without causing harm" The table following that diagram gives specific setup and hold times for those frames so it seems the manufacturer is keen for you to provide them.  "Are they here for a reason." Presumably so. You could ask the manufacturer why. They may not be inclined to tell you if inserting these frames is a workaround for some issue with the panels. They are likely to be more helpful if you are buying sufficiently large numbers of panels.